# change stroke-width inside a circular svg

Tags: html, svg

Trying to change `stroke-width` of `paths` inside a `svg`.

Both paths should be `9` instead of `3` and `5`.

As a result I'm getting deformed (not circular) paths.

Any help and a short explaination, pls.

```css
.single{
width:120px;
height:120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="single">
 <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="display: block; width: 100%;"><path d="M 50,50 m 0,-47.5 a 47.5,47.5 0 1 1 0,95 a 47.5,47.5 0 1 1 0,-95" stroke="#4598C9" stroke-width="3" fill-opacity="0"></path>
  
  <path d="M 50,50 m 0,-47.5 a 47.5,47.5 0 1 1 0,95 a 47.5,47.5 0 1 1 0,-95" stroke="#dd4b39" stroke-width="5" fill-opacity="0" class = "xpath" style="stroke-dasharray: 300, 300; stroke-dashoffset: 255;"></path></svg>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your shape is bigger than the viewBox if you make the stroke-width larger. One way to fix that is to change the viewBox sizing so the shape appears a little smaller and fits in the drawing area.

```css
.single{
width:120px;
height:120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="single">
 <svg viewBox="-3 -3 106 106" style="display: block; width: 100%;"><path d="M 50,50 m 0,-47.5 a 47.5,47.5 0 1 1 0,95 a 47.5,47.5 0 1 1 0,-95" stroke="#4598C9" stroke-width="9" fill-opacity="0"></path>
  
  <path d="M 50,50 m 0,-47.5 a 47.5,47.5 0 1 1 0,95 a 47.5,47.5 0 1 1 0,-95" stroke="#dd4b39" stroke-width="9" fill-opacity="0" class = "xpath" style="stroke-dasharray: 300, 300; stroke-dashoffset: 255;"></path></svg>
  </div>
```